# Detectar expresión regular al principio de palabra

Tags: javascript, python, json, regex

Estoy intentando encontrar una expresión regular que me resuelva la siguiente situación:

Tengo estos valores y quiero encontrar data_: (data_ seguido de 40 carácteres alfanuméricos)

```
{data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dasdcccx, not_data, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa933eqcsadd, other, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90d34244cd, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dc334dee}
```

Después de pasar la expresión regular tendría que sacarme este resultado:

```
{data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dasdcccx, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa933eqcsadd, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90d34244cd, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dc334dee}
```

Hay alguna expresión regular que me coja **data_** y los valores posteriores?

Cualquier aporte servirá de ayuda :)

Comment: Dices que tiene que ser el literal "data_" seguido de 40 números pero en el resultado que quieres obtener esos últimos 40 valores no son sólo números. ¿Buscas que sean solo números o puede contener letras? ¿Se podría colar alguna mayúscula o no quieres eso? ¿Hasta qué punto de la expresión has llegado? Debes haber intentado algo :)

Comment: Si, error mio. Busco que encuentre carácteres alfanuméricos. He encontrado algunas expresiones, pero no acaban de funcionar :/

Comment: Dices que tienes algunas regex pero que no acaban de funcionar. Puedes ponerlas en la pregunta y explicar qué resultado te han dado?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: `(data_\w+)` no te funciona? A mi me [parece que sí](https://regex101.com/r/bZQE3Y/1)

Comment: Gracias, @abulafia era justamente eso... :D, Antes la había visto, pero seguramente estaba mal escrita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependiendo si el grupo de captura es greedy o non-greedy la expresión regular que estás probando te va a devolver la primera ocurrencia o la última.

Suponiendo que `data` sea un string:

```
var data = `{data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dasdcccx, not_data, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa933eqcsadd, other, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90d34244cd, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dc334dee}`;
```

La ejecución de

```
/(data_\w{40})+/.exec(data)
```

Te va a devolver

```
[
"data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dasdcccx", 
"data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dasdcccx", 
index: 1, 
input: .... 
]
```

Puedes usar el `index` para iterar, avanzando en una cantidad de caracteres que es el `index` + 45 caracteres (el largo de data_ + 40 caracteres)

```js
var rx = /(data_\w{40})+/;
var data = '{data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dasdcccx, not_data, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa933eqcsadd, other, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90d34244cd, data_f5d3ffb70221d98940418e622010aa90dc334dee}';
var matches = [];
var match = rx.exec(data);
while (match !== null) {
  matches.push(match[0]);
  data = data.substr(match.index + 45);
  match = rx.exec(data);
}
console.log(matches);
```

En lenguajes que implementan PCRE (como PHP) se puede usar el modificador recursivo `(?R)`, pero en realidad nunca lo he ocupado así que no voy a entrar en eso.

Answer (score 4):

Esta expresión debería detectarte exactamente 40 caracteres después del 'data_':

```
^data_(\w{40})$
```

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias!!! Lo tendré en cuenta :)